# How can I media query an nth-child property that has an extended class as the target

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, media-queries

I apologize for the question as I know I am asking it wrong.  Please edit. Here is the issue I ran into regarding nth-child property.  I am developing on a chrome browser and I have also tested this in IE's latest browser too.

I came across the ability to target an nth-child(n+5) div and further select a class I wanted to set a property on.  Without a media query it works great.

here is the code:

```
div:nth-child(n+5) .clearing-thumbs li {
        padding-top: 0;
    }
```

The issue comes when I try to use a media query to do the exact same thing but start at n+3. The media query works but the nth child selector is ignored.

here is the code:

```
 @media #{$small-only} { div:nth-child(n+3) .clearing-thumbs li { padding-top: 0; }

    }
```

I know I am having this exact issue because when I add the media query and nth-child select a specific child property it works fine.

here is the code that works as normal

```
@media #{$small-only} { .clearing-thumbs li:nth-child(n+3) { padding-top: 35px; }

    }
```

So my question become is there anyway to do what I want by selecting the parent div and sub class the way I did originally.  I thought it was a really cool feature I figured out until the media query didn't work.

here is the html

```
<section class="thumbnail-section">
<div class="row collapse">
<div class="small-6 medium-3 left columns">
<ul class="clearing-thumbs clearing-feature" data-clearing>
  <li class="clearing-featured-img"><a href="/images/fullslide7.jpg"><img data-caption="caption here..." src="/images/fullslide7-320x200.jpg"></a></li>
  <li><a href="/images/fullslide7.jpg"><img data-caption="caption 2 here..." src="/images/fullslide7-320x200.jpg"></a></li>
  <li><a href="/images/fullslide7.jpg"><img data-caption="caption 3 here..." src="/images/fullslide7-320x200.jpg"></a></li>
  <li><a href="/images/fullslide7.jpg"><img data-caption="caption 3 here..." src="/images/fullslide7-320x200.jpg"></a></li>
  <li><a href="/images/fullslide7.jpg"><img data-caption="caption 3 here..." src="/images/fullslide7-320x200.jpg"></a></li>
  <li><a href="/images/fullslide7.jpg"><img data-caption="caption 3 here..." src="/images/fullslide7-320x200.jpg"></a></li>
  <li><a href="/images/fullslide7.jpg"><img data-caption="caption 3 here..." src="/images/fullslide7-320x200.jpg"></a></li>
  <li><a href="/images/fullslide7.jpg"><img data-caption="caption 3 here..." src="/images/fullslide7-320x200.jpg"></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="small-6 medium-3 left columns">
<ul class="clearing-thumbs clearing-feature" data-clearing>
  <li class="clearing-featured-img"><a href="/images/fullslide7.jpg"><img data-caption="caption here..." src="/images/fullslide7-320x200.jpg"></a></li>
  <li><a href="/images/fullslide7.jpg"><img data-caption="caption 2 here..." src="/images/fullslide7-320x200.jpg"></a></li>
  <li><a href="/images/fullslide7.jpg"><img data-caption="caption 3 here..." src="/images/fullslide7-320x200.jpg"></a></li>
  <li><a href="/images/fullslide7.jpg"><img data-caption="caption 3 here..." src="/images/fullslide7-320x200.jpg"></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="small-6 medium-3 left columns">
<ul class="clearing-thumbs clearing-feature" data-clearing>
  <li class="clearing-featured-img"><a href="/images/fullslide7.jpg"><img data-caption="caption here..." src="/images/fullslide7-320x200.jpg"></a></li>
  <li><a href="/images/fullslide7.jpg"><img data-caption="caption 2 here..." src="/images/fullslide7-320x200.jpg"></a></li>
  <li><a href="/images/fullslide7.jpg"><img data-caption="caption 3 here..." src="/images/fullslide7-320x200.jpg"></a></li>
  <li><a href="/images/fullslide7.jpg"><img data-caption="caption 3 here..." src="/images/fullslide7-320x200.jpg"></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="small-6 medium-3 left columns">
<ul class="clearing-thumbs clearing-feature" data-clearing>
  <li class="clearing-featured-img"><a href="/images/fullslide7.jpg"><img data-caption="caption here..." src="/images/fullslide7-320x200.jpg"></a></li>
  <li><a href="/images/fullslide7.jpg"><img data-caption="caption 2 here..." src="/images/fullslide7-320x200.jpg"></a></li>
  <li><a href="/images/fullslide7.jpg"><img data-caption="caption 3 here..." src="/images/fullslide7-320x200.jpg"></a></li>
  <li><a href="/images/fullslide7.jpg"><img data-caption="caption 3 here..." src="/images/fullslide7-320x200.jpg"></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="small-6 medium-3 left columns">
<ul class="clearing-thumbs clearing-feature" data-clearing>
  <li class="clearing-featured-img"><a href="/images/fullslide7.jpg"><img data-caption="caption here..." src="/images/fullslide7-320x200.jpg"></a></li>
  <li><a href="/images/fullslide7.jpg"><img data-caption="caption 2 here..." src="/images/fullslide7-320x200.jpg"></a></li>
  <li><a href="/images/fullslide7.jpg"><img data-caption="caption 3 here..." src="/images/fullslide7-320x200.jpg"></a></li>
  <li><a href="/images/fullslide7.jpg"><img data-caption="caption 3 here..." src="/images/fullslide7-320x200.jpg"></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="small-6 medium-3 left columns">
<ul class="clearing-thumbs clearing-feature" data-clearing>
  <li class="clearing-featured-img"><a href="/images/fullslide7.jpg"><img data-caption="caption here..." src="/images/fullslide7-320x200.jpg"></a></li>
  <li><a href="/images/fullslide7.jpg"><img data-caption="caption 2 here..." src="/images/fullslide7-320x200.jpg"></a></li>
  <li><a href="/images/fullslide7.jpg"><img data-caption="caption 3 here..." src="/images/fullslide7-320x200.jpg"></a></li>
  <li><a href="/images/fullslide7.jpg"><img data-caption="caption 3 here..." src="/images/fullslide7-320x200.jpg"></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="small-6 medium-3 left columns">
<ul class="clearing-thumbs clearing-feature" data-clearing>
  <li class="clearing-featured-img"><a href="/images/fullslide7.jpg"><img data-caption="caption here..." src="/images/fullslide7-320x200.jpg"></a></li>
  <li><a href="/images/fullslide7.jpg"><img data-caption="caption 2 here..." src="/images/fullslide7-320x200.jpg"></a></li>
  <li><a href="/images/fullslide7.jpg"><img data-caption="caption 3 here..." src="/images/fullslide7-320x200.jpg"></a></li>
  <li><a href="/images/fullslide7.jpg"><img data-caption="caption 3 here..." src="/images/fullslide7-320x200.jpg"></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="small-6 medium-3 left columns">
<ul class="clearing-thumbs clearing-feature" data-clearing>
  <li class="clearing-featured-img"><a href="/images/fullslide7.jpg"><img data-caption="caption here..." src="/images/fullslide7-320x200.jpg"></a></li>
  <li><a href="/images/fullslide7.jpg"><img data-caption="caption 2 here..." src="/images/fullslide7-320x200.jpg"></a></li>
  <li><a href="/images/fullslide7.jpg"><img data-caption="caption 3 here..." src="/images/fullslide7-320x200.jpg"></a></li>
  <li><a href="/images/fullslide7.jpg"><img data-caption="caption 3 here..." src="/images/fullslide7-320x200.jpg"></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Need to see your HTML. I recall answering a similar question in the distant past but I can't say for sure if it will apply to yours without seeing your HTML.

Comment: Also, please test early and test often. Chrome is notorious for breaking the spec in various ways that will make other browsers seem like the problem when they're just following the spec to the letter.

Comment: I added in the html.  I have only tested it on chrome you may be correct.

Comment: @BoltClock I can confirm the exact same mistake/bug/feature is happening in IE as well.